# How to capture a UIView snapshot while animating images inside that view

Tags: ios, objective-c

A `UIView` contains an animating image (`UIImage`).

I want to take a screenshot of the parent view in a loop using `renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`

While capturing screenshot of the parent view (`previewContainer`), it doesn't capture image as animated.

Only the last position of the image in the view is captured every time (will display in `thmbView`).

**code to capture**

```
- (void) startCapturing{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(previewContainer.frame.size);
[previewContainer.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
thmb.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


double delayInSeconds = 0.2;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    if (sec++ < 15) {
    [self startCapturing];
    }
});}
```

**code to animate**

```
- (void) animate{
    CABasicAnimation * appearance =[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    [appearance setValue:@"animation1" forKey:@"id"];
    appearance.delegate = self;
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:)];
    appearance.duration = 10;
    appearance.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    appearance.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:340];
    appearance.repeatCount = 1;
    appearance.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    appearance.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [imgPreview.layer addAnimation:appearance forKey:@"transform.translation.y"];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Only way to take screenshots of animation in the view that you can render the presentation layer.

Instead of this line

```
[previewContainer.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Use this

```
[previewContainer.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the screenshot method and try it, no matter view or animation action your can get UIImage object.

```
- (UIImage *)screenshotImageOfItem:(UIView *)item 
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(item.bounds.size, item.isOpaque, 0.0f);

[item.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```